# Infusionsoft populate custom field via API

Tags: infusionsoft

I am trying to set the value of a custom field that belongs to a contact via the Infusionsoft API.

When I try to create or update the contact with the custom field value set I receive the following response:

`[NoFieldFound]No field found: Contact.InitialSiteVisitTime`

Which leads me to believe that the custom field value is stored in a different table. Can anyone please tell me the name of the table that holds Infusionsofts custom field values?

Answer (score 1):

Infusionsoft automatically prefixes custom field names with an underscore. Adding the underscore to the name allows to populate this value via the API successfully.

Note, that custom fields API names (the way they stored in Infusionsoft database) not always equal to how you name a custom field on creation.

[This article](http://help.infusionsoft.com/related-articles/backend-database-names-for-custom-fields) shows where your actual custom fields API names are listed.