# Adding a CustomField to Infusuionsoft contact

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I am trying to modify an existing integration with Infusionsoft that uses the Novak Infusionsoft PHP SDK.

The config.php file has a few custom fields defined in config.php like

```
//To Add Custom Fields, use the addCustomField method like below.
//Infusionsoft_Contact::addCustomField('_LeadScore');
Infusionsoft_Contact::addCustomField('_FooBar');
Infusionsoft_Contact::addCustomField('_BarFoo');
```

and that all works.  I want to add another custom field for a text field named "Best Describes Me" in Infusionsoft and added what I thought would be the appropriate line

```
Infusionsoft_Contact::addCustomField('_BestDescribesMe');
```

But putting that line in gets an error:

[NoFieldFound]No field found: Contact._BestDescribesMe Attempted: 1 time(s).

I have been searching to see if there is anything else to be done either in the PHP toolkit or in Infusionsoft, but cannot find anything.  I would actually expect that I have to do something in Infusionsoft to make the custom field externally available, but cannot find anything about that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: didn't it provide Gui to do that. I have looked to infusion-soft and it have GUI to add custom fields.

Comment: We have the custom fields in Infusionsoft, the issue is accessing them via the API.  In our case that is the Novak Infusionsoft PHP SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infusionsoft populate custom field via API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837759/infusionsoft-populate-custom-field-via-api)

Answer (score 0):

I fid find the solution.  The actual field name in Infusionsoft may not be the same as what is displayed.  You have to dig into the Backend Database Names for Custom Fields as described on this page:

http://help.infusionsoft.com/related-articles/backend-database-names-for-custom-fields

1. Go to Admin > Settings in the main navigation menu
2. Go to the custom field section, select a field type from the drop-down, and then click on Go.
3. Click on the View the field database names (for the API ) link.
4. The database field names will be listed in a new window.

The backend name is what needs to be put into the SDK config.php